# Test turbo stream action using Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, turbo

I am doing a rspec test for a controller action that use turbo stream :

```rb
  describe 'GET /CONTROLLER_NAME' do

    it 'return a turbo stream answer' do
      get :index, as: :turbo_stream
      expect(response).to eq Mime[:turbo_stream]
    end
  end

end
```

```
Failure/Error: expect(response).to eq Mime[:turbo_stream]

       expected: #<Mime::Type:0x00007f7d9c2e1ff0 @synonyms=[], @symbol=:turbo_stream, @string="text/vnd.turbo-stream.html", @hash=2866392594387537360>
            got: #<ActionDispatch::TestResponse:0x00007f7d976945f8 @mon_data=#<Monitor:0x00007f7d97694580>, @mon_data_...oller::TestRequest GET "http://test.host/CONTROLLER_NAME.turbo_stream" for 0.0.0.0>>
```

How do you make a get query with turbo stream in a controller test?

Answer (score 12):

you should check `response.media_type` to be `Mime[:turbo_stream]` instead of just `request`. check [turbo stream test helpers](https://github.com/hotwired/turbo-rails/blob/main/lib/turbo/test_assertions.rb)

```rb
  describe 'GET /CONTROLLER_NAME' do
    it 'return a turbo stream answer' do
      get :index, as: :turbo_stream
      expect(response.media_type).to eq Mime[:turbo_stream]
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend moving to requests tests because controller tests [have been deprecated](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/1838), here is an example, thought:

```
# spec/controllers/patients_controller_spec.rb
require "rails_helper"

RSpec.describe PatientsController, type: :controller do      
  describe "GET /patients" do
    it "returns patients list" do
      get :index, format: :turbo_stream
      expect(response).to have_http_status(:ok)
    end
  end
end
```

And here is the request test just for future reference:

```
# spec/requests/patients_spec.rb
require "rails_helper"

RSpec.describe "patients", type: :request do      
  describe "GET /patients" do
    it "returns patients list" do
      get patients_path(format: :turbo_stream)
      expect(response).to have_http_status(:ok)
    end
  end
end
```

You can also access some response's attributes like response.status, response.content_type

I don't own these links but may help you find the right assertion:

- https://rspec.info/features/6-0/rspec-rails/request-specs/request-spec
- https://discuss.hotwired.dev/t/looking-for-resources-on-how-to-use-rspec-with-hotwire/3284